# Navigation controller with tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tableViewController embedded in my tab bar controller. When a cell is tapped, a segue is launched to another view controller to show the details of that object. However, the Back button is not appearing in the viewDetail. I tried embedding the view into a separate Navigation Controller but that didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong? I currently have Tab Bar Controller -> tableView -> Navigation Controller -> viewDetail (need Back button here to return to tableView).

Here's what I have right now:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: no, you should do tabbar->navigation controller->tableview->detail view

Comment: You just have the organization wrong. Currently you have Tab Bar Controller -> tableView -> Navigation Controller -> viewDetail. It should be Tab Bar -> tableview. Tableview cell -> View detail. Navigation should be separate pointing to table view. Nothing should be pointing to navigation. It should just point to tableview

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each `UIViewController` in `UITabBarController` could be embedded in an `UINavigationController` at your convenience, that way you'll be able to use all of the features that you need.

Basically, you need to select the tableViewController, click on `Editor` menu item, select `Embed in` and click on `Navigation Controller`, ta daa.

[image: UINavigationController Example]

You can show or hide `Navigation Bar` if you need it using `Interface Builder` or programmatically in your Detail viewController  as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: is this approach should be used in general ?

Comment: Bar visibility option was very useful to disable it on the following controller. Thanks.
This option is called `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` on Xcode 9, on the Attributes Inspector tab.

Answer (score 4):

Set NavigationController to TabBarController, then set NavigationController's rootViewController to TableViewController.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just have the organization wrong. Currently you have Tab Bar Controller -> tableView -> Navigation Controller -> viewDetail. It should be Tab Bar -> tableview -> View detail. Navigation should be separate pointing to table view. Nothing should be pointing to navigation. It should just point to tableview

[image]

It should look something like the above picture

Comment: This is a very good solution, I think. I had a doubt if it'll work or not, but just tried to do the same only from code and it worked like a charm. This is perfect in the way it does not require any additional "show/hide" of navigation bars or the tab bar.
Great answer!